# Image blocks out Canvas

Tags: wpf

```
<Image Width="640" Height="480"  Name="ImageControl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Canvas Width="620" Height="480" Name="myCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="10" Name="Circle1" Canvas.ZIndex="99" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="30" Name="Circle2" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="50" Name="Circle3" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="70" Name="Circle4" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="90" Name="Circle5" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="110" Name="Circle6" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="130" Name="Circle7" />
    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="150" Name="Circle8" />
</Canvas>
```

I have an Image and a Canvas in the same cell in a Grid. The idea is to place the 8 red ellipses over the image. The Image currently has no source as the Kinect is used to supply the image. When it first loads the red ellipses can be seen for a split second until the image loads and then they aren't seen again.

I have tried changed the order of the elements, the ZIndex of the Canvas, the ZIndex of the Grid all with no avail.

```
this.ImageControl.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
                imageFrame.Width,
                imageFrame.Height,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                null,
                this.pixelData,
                stride);
```

This is how the Kinect stream image is assigned to the Image source.

Comment: This should work with regular images, maybe the problem is in the way images obtained from kinect get painted, maybe it bypasses WPF drawing completely, like ActiveX containers do.

Comment: I've added how the image source is assigned in code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a different imagesource? 
It works for me. 
Try to use one of the Example Pictures from Windows.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="537" Width="721">
  <Grid>
    <Image Width="640" Height="480"  Name="ImageControl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="Desert.jpg" />
    <Canvas Width="620" Height="480" Name="myCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="10" Name="Circle1" Canvas.ZIndex="99" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="30" Name="Circle2" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="50" Name="Circle3" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="70" Name="Circle4" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="90" Name="Circle5" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="110" Name="Circle6" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="130" Name="Circle7" />
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="610" Canvas.Top="150" Name="Circle8" />
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I head this in my code

```
myCanvas.Children.Clear();
```

This was clearing the line skeleton drawn on the canvas once it was no longer needed and this was removing the ellipses as well.